# Para que serve o set no Python?

Tags: python

O que é e para que serve o `set` no Python?

```
test = set([1, 2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Set` é uma collection que representa conjunto.

Essa coleção tem como caracteristica ser desordenada e ter os elementos únicos, ou seja, não existe repetição de elementos nesse tipo de collection.

Existem também métodos que fazem operações de conjunto, como por exemplo union e intersection que respectivamente retornam todos os elementos de dois `set` e os elementos que eles tem em comum.

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> b = {3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> print a.union(b)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [2, 4, 3]
>>> print set(l1).intersection(l2)
set([2, 3])
```

Referência
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html