# Tipo set no Python é ordenado?

Tags: python, set

Ao criar uma variável assim:

```
a = {1,2,5,1,3}
```

Ela acaba retornando uma variável do tipo `set`. Porém, na documentação do Python, é dito que é impossível criar um `set` sem a função `set()`.
Além disso, `set` não tem ordem, porém ao exibir a variável me resulta os números em ordem crescente.

O que é um set?

Comment: Na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets): "*Curly braces or the set() function can be used to create sets.*". Ou seja, é possível, sim, criar um `set` com `{}`.

Comment: Ainda assim, "A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements", logo não deveria ter ordem. Por que me resulta num set em ordem crescente?

Comment: Relacionada a isso: [Qual a diferença entre ordered, unordered e sorted?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Para que serve o set no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77699/5878)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Para que serve o set no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77699/para-que-serve-o-set-no-python)

Comment: Logo, o unordered apenas significa que nao consigo acessar pelo index?

Comment: Significa que não há garantias de qual será a ordem dos resultados.

Answer (score 7):

Você está confundindo os termos `unordered` e `sorted`. A pergunta do Maniero explica muito bem cada termo:

[Qual a diferença entre ordered, unordered e sorted?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/5878)

Para mais detalhes sobre o que é e quando usar um `set`, veja a discussão em:

[Para que serve o set no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77699/5878)

Apenas porquê um exemplo que você testou retornou um conjunto sortido não significa que o tipo será sortido sempre.

Faça um teste bem simples:

Gere um grande número de conjuntos com valores aleatórios e verifique se todos estão na mesma ordem que sua respectiva lista sortida.

```
import random

# Efetua 1000 testes:
for _ in range(1000):

    # Gera um conjunto de 10 números inteiros entre 0 e 9:
    a = set(random.randint(0, 9) for __ in range(10))

    # Verifica se o conjunto é igual à sua respectiva lista sortida:
    if list(a) != sorted(a):

        # Se for diferente, exibe o conjunto:
        print(a)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/gbRtZt).

Veja a quantidade de conjuntos que foram criados que não ficaram sortidos como você esperava. A ordem que é retornado um `set` dependerá da implementação interna na linguagem e não há qualquer garantia que esses valores estarão sortidos ou sempre na mesma ordem em todos os ambientes. O tipo `set` também não possui índice, ou seja, não é possível acessar um determinada posição através do índice:

```
a = {1, 2, 5, 1, 3}

print(a[0])
```

Retorna o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "python", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: A confusão dos termos é muito comum, eu aprendi errado, passei a vida inteira usando errado e até hoje tenho dificuldade de usar certo, mas desde que aprendi, tento :)

Comment: Acho que a confusão geralmente se dá porque no português utilizamos o "ordenado" para um conjunto que segue determinada ordem. Eu também passei minha vida achando que eram a mesma coisa, até que vi sua pergunta/resposta e fui pesquisar mais a respeito.

Comment: Sim, eu **acho** até que em outras áreas intercambiem sem problemas. Pelo menos vc viu q eu posso errar, mas ñ saio proferindo besteiras a esmo por aí :D