# Remover inteiros repetidos lista em Python

Tags: python, lista

Gostaria de remover os inteiros repetidos de uma lista e retornar uma lista nova.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
```

O resultado teria que ser esse:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada no `set` https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77699/para-que-serve-o-set-no-python

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Para que serve o set no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77699/para-que-serve-o-set-no-python)

Comment: Mas o set atualiza uma lista, eu gostaria de um algoritmo ou então alguma lib nativa do Python que removesse items da lista duplicados.

Comment: Qual o problema em usar o set, @GuilhermeIA?

Comment: Eu não tinha entendido exatamente o que é o `set`, realmente é uma duplicata. Obrigado @LINQ e @Leonardo Pessoa

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada neste [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268994/exercicio-ordena%c3%a7%c3%a3o-lista).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `set` faz justamente isto. Se você fizer questão que o tipo do resultado seja uma `list`, é só fazer a conversão do  `set` para tal

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8] 
b = set(a) # Conjunto a partir de 'a', vai remover todos os repetidos

c = list(b) # lista a partir de 'b', vai converter o set numa list

print(a) # [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
print(b) # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
print(c) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Tem só um erro na 4 linha, o parâmetro da lista é o `b` e não `c`. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja apenas remover os inteiros repetidos da lista citada, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]

nova_lista = list()
for c in lista:
    if c not in nova_lista:
        nova_lista.append(c)

print(nova_lista)
```

Observe que neste algoritmo o `for` percorre `lista` e, se cada valor de `c` não existir em `nova_lista`, adiciona-o em `nova_lista`. E, caso contrário, não o adiciona.

Ao final teremos a `nova_lista` formada por todos os elementos de `lista` sem os valores repetidos.

Agora, se for necessário generalizar a lógica deste algoritmo para tratar casos em que teremos listas variadas, podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
lista = sorted(list(map(int, input('Digite todos os valores da lista: ').split())))

nova_lista = list()
for c in lista:
    if c not in nova_lista:
        nova_lista.append(c)

print(nova_lista)
```

Quando executamos este segundo algoritmo recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite todos os valores da lista:`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores da lista na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

A parir desse momento o algoritmo capturará todos os valores digitados, os converterá para `inteiros` e os armazenará, ordenadamente de forma crescente em `lista`. Em seguida, o `for` percorrerá `lista` e, se cada valor de `c` não existir em `nova_lista`, adiciona-o em `nova_lista`. E, caso contrário, não o adiciona.

Se as futuras listas utilizadas neste segundo algoritmo contiverem elementos de valor real, basta mudar o tipo de dado de `int` para `float`.