# Exercicio ordenação lista

Tags: python, lista

Boa tarde,

Estou desenvolvendo um exercicio e em um momento tenho que ordenar uma lista e retirar elementos repetido, para isso realizo a conversão para set e depois converto para lista novamente:

```
    def remove(lista):
       lista2 = set(lista)
       lista = list(lista2)
       return lista
```

no entanto realizando um teste, obtenho sempre um resultado inesperado, na conversão de [7,3,33,12,3,3,3,7,12,100] ao invés de obter [3,7,12,33,100], recebo como resultado [33, 3, 12, 100, 7], alguém pode me auxiliar a encontrar esse erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é erro, simplesmente não ordenaste a lista após removeres os duplicados:

```
def remove(lista):
   return sorted(set(lista)) # <--- ordena lista
```

[DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Para retirar os valores repetidos e ordenar a lista que você `citou` no exemplo, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
numeros = [7, 3, 33, 12, 3, 3, 3, 7, 12, 100]

resultado = list()
for c in numeros:
    if c not in resultado:
        resultado.append(c)
resultado.sort()
print(resultado)
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/pzdizetk-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Agora, se você pretende trabalhar com listas de `tamanhos` e `elementos` variados, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
numeros = list(map(int, input('Digite os elementos da lista: ').split()))

resultado = list()
for c in numeros:
    if c not in resultado:
        resultado.append(c)
resultado.sort()
print(resultado)
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/wdzbokgg-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que quando você executar este `último` algoritmo, você terá que digitar `todos` os elementos da lista na `mesma linha`, separados por um `espaço`.