# remover duplicados pela prespetiva de tuplos

Tags: python, tupla

Tenho este código a funcionar, no entanto queria fazê-lo da prespetiva dos tuplos.
Podem auxiliar?

```
def remove_repetidos(lst):
    lista = [] #lista vazia
    for i in lst:
        if i not in lista:
            lista.append(i)
    lista.sort() #ordenada a lista por ordem ascendente
    return lista
```

Comment: Em que momento exatamente você gostaria de aplicar as tuplas?

Comment: Entretanto fiz um outro que não está a funcionar e não sei bem porquê.

Comment: def sensas(lst):
    lst_unica = [i for n, i in enumerate(lst_com_unicos) if i not in lst_com_unicos[n + 1:]]
    for lst_resulta_unica in lst_unica:
        return lst_resulta_unica

Comment: Esse outro código parece estar errado. Você utiliza uma variável `lst_com_unicos` que não foi definida.

Comment: desculpa sou nova no python, achei que ele assumia. vou refazer, já aqui coloco

Comment: def sensas(lst):
    lst_com_unicos = ()
    lst_unica = [i for n, i in enumerate(lst_com_unicos) if i not in lst_com_unicos[n + 1:]]
    for lst_resulta_unica in lst_unica:
        return lst_resulta_unica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não consegue utilizar tuplas para fazer o mesmo que fez com a lista pelo fato que as tuplas são imutáveis e, assim, não é possível adicionar novos valores. Para adicionar um novo valor na tupla é necessário criar uma nova tupla com os valores atuais mais o novo e essa adição é feita a partir de uma estrutura auxiliar.

Por exemplo, é possível fazer tuda a lógica utilizando listas e apenas retornar como tupla:

```
def remove_repetidos(lst):
    lista = [] #lista vazia
    for i in lst:
        if i not in lista:
            lista.append(i)
    lista.sort() #ordenada a lista por ordem ascendente
    return tuple(lista)
```

E para criar uma nova tupla adicionando o novo valor ficaria algo como:

```
def remove_repetidos(lst):
    unicos = tuple()
    for valor in lst:
        if valor not in unicos:
            unicos += (valor,)
    return unicos
```

Mas atente-se ao fato que mesmo que pareça que apenas está modificando a tupla na verdade você criando uma nova tupla e sobrescrevendo a antiga.

A maneira mais simples de remover os itens duplicados de uma sequência é utilizando o `set`, como pode ser visto em [Remover inteiros repetidos lista em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268525/5878)

Comment: Obrigada. Era isso mesmo. no entanto eu precisava que sito fucnionasse tanto para inteiros como para texto. remove_repetidos((a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,d,c,b)) e neste caso diz-me que o 'a' is not defined. Será que tenho de validar os parametros de entrada?

Comment: @PipocaInsuflada Não, apenas utilizar *strings* corretamente. As *strings* são definidas entre aspas: `('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', ...)`

Comment: Obrigada faltava isso sim