# Remover duplicados na prespetivas de tuplos

Tags: python, python-3.x

O seguinte código dá erro quando corro

```py
def sensas(lst):
    lst_unica = [i for n, i in enumerate(lst_com_unicos) if i not in lst_com_unicos[n + 1:]]
    for lst_resulta_unica in lst_unica:
        return lst_resulta_unica
```

---

erros:

> 1)
>   sensas((a,b,c,a,b,c))
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     Python Shell, prompt 3, line 1
>   NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>
> 2)
>   sensas((1,2,3,1,2,3))
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     Python Shell, prompt 4, line 1
>     File "/Users/Rute/Desktop/untitled-1a.py", line 39, in 
>       lst_unica = [i for n, i in enumerate(lst_com_unicos) if i not in lst_com_unicos[n + 1:]]
>   NameError: global name 'lst_com_unicos' is not defined
>
> 3)
>   ensas([1,2,3,1,2,3])
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     Python Shell, prompt 5, line 1
>     File "/Users/Rute/Desktop/untitled-1a.py", line 39, in 
>       lst_unica = [i for n, i in enumerate(lst_com_unicos) if i not in lst_com_unicos[n + 1:]]
>   NameError: global name 'lst_com_unicos' is not defined

Comment: você não tem uma variável chamada `lst_com_unicos` na sua função ou com variável global. Você terá que cria-la. Aconselho-lhe a estudar mais os `Tracebacks`, entender-los irão lhe ajudar bastante :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- De acordo com o primeiro erro, seu código tem essa função `sensas((a,b,c,a,b,c))`, mas não encontrou a variável ***a***. Onde está a criação desta variável?
- Nos erros 2 e 3, seu código tem essa função `lst_unica = [i for n, i in enumerate(lst_com_unicos) if i not in lst_com_unicos[n + 1:]]`, mas não encontrou a variável ***lst_com_unicos***. Onde está a criação desta variável?

Comment: Já consegui obter a resposta neste outro post. Obrigada. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/417835/remover-duplicados-pela-prespetiva-de-tuplos/417853?noredirect=1#comment813424_417853