# Como acessar os elementos de um conjunto (set)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Estou estudando sobre conjuntos ([`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)) em Python porque vou usar em um algoritmo de achar caminhos em um grafo, é para uma disciplina da faculdade que estou tendo.

Criei dois exemplos de conjunto usando duas notações distintas. Olhe o exemplo de ilustração:

```
foo = {1, 1, 5, 'gato', 'Oie'}
baz = set([2, 19, 51, 'stack', 'py'])

print(foo)
print(baz)
```

No entanto, quando eu tento acessar algum valor dos dois conjuntos `foo` ou `baz` usando indexação `baz[0]` ele retorna um erro dizendo que o objeto não suporta indexação, veja:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "jdoodle.py", line 11, in <module>
>     print(baz[2])
> TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
> Command exited with non-zero status 1
> ```

## Pergunta

Assim sendo, eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia acessar os elementos de um conjunto de maneira individual?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A estrutura de dados `set` do Python não tem ordenação - então não faria sentido dizer "me de o elemento na posição 0" (meuset[0])  - no entanto, ela é iterável!

Então se você tem uma ação para executar com cada elemento de um conjunto, pode simplesmente fazer:

```
for element in my_set:
    # do things with 'element'
```

Isso 'e o suficiente, e a forma mais correta para a maioria dos casos. Se você realmente precisar fazer várias operações em elementos arbitrários do set, pode colocar esses elementos numa lista - como é um iterável:

```
minha_lista = list(meu_set)
```

Funciona - mas a lista não vai estar em nenhuma ordem específica - (então, por que não usar o `for` acima). Se você precisa de alguma ordem, pode usar o built-in `sorted` que devolve uma lista, mas ordena os elementos - então, se quiser os elementos em ordem alfabética:

```
 minha_lista = sorted(meu_set)
```

Ou, se quiser uma ordem arbitrária, pode usar o parâmetro `key` para o sorted - vamos supor que queira uma lista dos elementos no seu set em ordem crescente do comprimento:

```
minha_lista = sorted(meu_set, key=len)
```

Isso vai usar o retorno da função `len` em cada item para fazer a ordenação. Detalhes osbre o sorted é que os elementos do  `set` são comparados entre si, então não funcionaria para os conjuntos com tipos de objetos misturados dos seus exemplos (pode funcionar se você escrever uma função `key` que funcione para os vários tipos de objetos).

Answer (score 8):

O `set` tem como finalidade [definir uma lista única de elementos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77699/para-que-serve-o-set-no-python).

Uma foram de conseguir fazer isso seria converter para `list` e obter o valor através do índice.

Assim:

```
a = set([1, 2, 3, 4])

print(list(a)[0])
```

## ATUALIZAÇÃO

o `set` do Python é uma coleção de elementos desordenada e, conforme uma resposta que li no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329308/how-to-get-index-of-element-in-set-object#18329412), não faz sentido tentar acessar a mesma por um índice.

Veja a tradução

> Um `set` é apenas uma coleção desordenada de elementos únicos. Então, um elemento ou está em um conjunto ou não está. Isso significa que nenhum elemento em um conjunto possui um índice.

Isso significa que, em um conjunto (`set`), o objetivo é apenas reunir determinados elementos em uma coleção, de maneira única. A posição em que o elemento é alocado pouco importa, já que esse não é o objetivo de `set`.

O que pode ser feito em tais casos é converter `set` para uma `list` e propôr alguma ordem lógica para sua estrutura.

Creio que, no seu caso, o ideia seja usar o tipo de estrutura certa para seus dados.

Por exemplo, em um servidor websocket que desenvolvi, eu utilizei `set` para adicionar as conexões que eram feitas no servidor de maneira única. A ordem no meu caso não importava, mas apenas o fato de ser uma coleção de registros únicos.

Se eu precisasse utilizar para saber quem entrou primeiro, poderia utilizar um `list`. Se eu quisesse nomear cada conexão pelo por um ID único, usaria `dict`.

Ou seja, cada estrutura deve ser usada para o caso correto.

Comment: "Por alguma razão" > A razão é que elementos de `set` não possuem "ordem" então não podem ser indexados de uma forma que faça sentido. Ao converter em lista com `list(a)` como você fez, não há como garantir que o elemento `1` seja o primeiro da lista, ele pode cair em outra posição. Uma forma é usar `sorted(a)` o que garante que os elementos estarão em ordem numérica.

Comment: Eu ainda não tive tendo de adicionar mais referência, estou agarrado aqui, kkkkk.

Comment: [Nestas respostas do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order) aparecem algumas maneiras de manter a ordem. No primeiro exemplo, com uma entrada `[2, 60, 19, 51, 'stack', 'py', 60, 'stack']` a saída é `[2, 60, 19, 51, 'stack', 'py']`