# Como simplificar o comando if em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, booleano

Existe algum modo em que eu possa simplificar essa linha de código em Python:

```
if X = 1 or X = 2 or X = 3 or X = 4:
```

eu estava tentando da seguinte forma:

```
if X = {1 or 2 or 3 or 4}:
```

Porém ao tentar assim dá erro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Usando Array

Você pode usar o "in", veja este exemplo

```
X = 2
if X in [1, 2, 3, 4]: 
    print("ok")
```

Eu representei os valores usando um array [1, 2, 3, 4], então eu uso o "in" para verificar se o valor de "X" esta dentro do array.

## Usando Tupla

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Como-simplificar-o-comando-if-em-python/10607?id=10607)

Seguindo a dica do nosso amigo [Giovanni Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/50856/giovanni-nunes)

```
X = 2
if X in (1, 2, 3, 4): 
    print("ok")
```

> Usar uma tupla a invés da lista dá para economizar alguns vários bytes por if

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Como-simplificar-o-comando-if-em-python-2/10613?id=10613)

## Usando Range

Como é uma sequencia é possível usar `range`

```
X = 2
if X in range(1, 5): 
    print("ok")
```

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Como-simplificar-o-comando-if-em-python-3/10630?id=10630)

Comment: E se `X = True`? xD

Comment: Se usar "or", ele entra da mesma forma usando True :P

Comment: Python é igual ao php né, 1 é True é a mesma coisa

Comment: Quase isso, no Python o `bool` herda de `int`, ficando `True` sendo `int(1)` e `False` sendo `int(0)`. O *problema* só ocorre se a lista de valores possuir 0 e/ou 1.

Comment: da pra fazer assim `if X in [1, 2, 3, 4] and type(X) != bool:`, mas fica feio :P

Comment: Entendi, vivendo e aprendendo :)

Comment: Se você usar uma tupla a invés da lista dá para economizar alguns vários bytes por `if`.

Comment: Resposta editada :)

Answer (score 3):

Como visto na resposta do @Wictor Chaves, você pode utilizar listas ou tuplas, mas vou te trazer mais uma opção: os conjuntos (`set`).

Um conjunto armazena valores semelhantes entre si e, por definição, únicos dentro do conjunto. Sem contar que o acesso aos valores e a verificação se possui determinado valor tende a ser otimizados em relação à lista e tupla.

Reescrevendo seu código, ficaria assim:

```
if X in {1, 2, 3, 4}:
```

Você pode ler mais sobre conjuntos nessa pergunta aqui: [Como acessar os elementos de um conjunto (set)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327948/como-acessar-os-elementos-de-um-conjunto-set?r=SearchResults)

Comment: Créditos pro @Anderson Carlos Woss por parte da resposta.