# Comparar letra 'E' em python

Tags: python, string

Tenho este código que basicamente percorre a lista `new_users` e verifica se já existe alguns usuário dentro de `current_users`.

Quando meu `if` faz a conversão dos nomes de `new_users` para maiúsculas, minúsculas e etc, ele falha em uma possibilidade, que é quando o nome 'ze' esta assim: 'zE'. Ou qualquer outro nome com final 'E' na lista `current_users`.

Coloquei outros nomes na lista current_users com a letra 'E' no final e meu código falha em verificar. O que posso fazer para converter as duas listas em `lower()` e verificar se existe algum usuário repetido?

```
current_users = ['ze', 'carmo', 'sofia', 'jeff', 'isa']
new_users = ['ze', 'didao', 'edi', 'taria', 'sofia']


for new_user in new_users:

    if new_user.lower() not in current_users \
            and new_user.upper() not in current_users\
            and new_user.title() not in current_users\
            and new_user.lower() not in current_users:
        print('O nome "' + new_user.title() + '" está disponível.')
    else:
       print('Forneça outro nome.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema não é só a letra "E", e sim o fato de que o código falha quando a lista `current_users` possui nomes que misturam letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Afinal, somente no `new_user` que você transforma tudo em maiúsculas ou minúsculas (no seu caso, você está comparando `ze`, `Ze` e `ZE` com `zE`, e aí não vai funcionar mesmo).

Se quer fazer comparações *case insensitive*, pode usar o [método `casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold). Este método é similar a [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower), mas segundo a documentação, ele é mais "agressivo" e trata casos especiais, como por exemplo o [caractere `ß`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm), que quando transformado para maiúsculo, se torna "SS" (então `'ß'.upper().lower()` retorna "ss"):

```
print('ß'.lower() == 'SS'.lower()) # False
print('ß'.casefold() == 'SS'.casefold()) # True
```

Claro que para letras de `a` a `z` não acentuadas, não vai fazer tanta diferença assim usar `lower()` ou `casefold()`, mas enfim.

Sendo assim, basta aplicar `casefold()` na lista de usuários atuais, e também em cada usuário que você está verificando:

```
current_users = ['ZE', 'carmo', 'SofiA', 'jeff', 'isa']
new_users = ['ze', 'didao', 'edi', 'taria', 'sofia']

current_users_fold = list(map(lambda user: user.casefold(), current_users))
for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.casefold() not in current_users_fold:
        print('O nome "' + new_user.title() + '" está disponível.')
    else:
       print('Forneça outro nome.')
```

Primeiro eu uso [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para criar outra lista, contendo a versão *casefolded* dos usuários atuais. Depois eu aplico o `casefold()` para cada novo usuário que estou verificando.

A saída é:

```
Forneça outro nome.
O nome "Didao" está disponível.
O nome "Edi" está disponível.
O nome "Taria" está disponível.
Forneça outro nome.
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) para encontrar a intersecção entre as duas listas (ou seja, os usuários já existentes), e usar esta lista para verificar os não-existentes:

```
def ajusta(s):
    return s.casefold()

existentes = list( set(map(ajusta, current_users)) & set(map(ajusta, new_users)) )
nao_existentes = [ new_user for new_user in new_users if new_user.casefold() not in existentes]
print(existentes) # ['sofia', 'ze']
print(nao_existentes) # ['didao', 'edi', 'taria']
```

Uma vez tendo as duas listas (usuários já existentes e que ainda não existem), você pode usá-las da maneira que quiser.

Comment: Obrigado, estou aprendendo python cada ajuda é bem vinda. Editei o código com base no seu e deu certinho :)

Answer (score 2):

No seu código, o que está acontecendo é que você só está fazendo transformações no `new_user` e não no `current_users`, uma maneira de resolver isso seria normalizando as duas listas e só depois comparar, por exemplo:

```
current_users = ['zE', 'carmo', 'sofia', 'jeff', 'isa']
new_users = ['ze', 'didao', 'edi', 'taria', 'sofia']

current_users_lower = [current_user.lower() for current_user in current_users]
new_users_lower = [new_user.lower() for new_user in new_users ]

for new_user in new_users_lower:

    if new_user not in current_users_lower:
        print('O nome "' + new_user + '" está disponível.')
    else:
       print('"' + new_user + '" não está disponível, forneça outro nome.')
```

Outra maneira seria utilizando o [set](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77699/para-que-serve-o-set-no-python), por exemplo:

```
current_users = ['zE', 'carmo', 'sofia', 'jeff', 'isa']
new_users = ['ze', 'didao', 'edi', 'taria', 'sofia']

current_users_lower = {current_user.lower() for current_user in current_users}
new_users_lower = {new_user.lower() for new_user in new_users }
duplicated = current_users_lower.intersection(new_users_lower)

print('Nomes já utilizados: {}'.format(', '.join(duplicated)))
print('Nomes disponíveis: {}'.format(', '.join(new_users_lower - duplicated)))
```

Comment: Sua versão com `set` ficou melhor que a minha, esqueci que dá para subtrair... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bem, você basicamente precisa converter todos os nomes da lista `current_users` para minúsculo. Veja o código abaixo:

```
current_users = ['zE', 'carmo', 'sofia', 'jeff', 'isa']
new_users = ['ze', 'didao', 'edi', 'taria', 'sofia']

# Converte todos os nomes da lista current_users para minúsculo.
c_users = []
for user in current_users:
    c_users.append(user.lower())
current_users = c_users

for new_user in new_users:

    if new_user.lower() not in current_users:
        print('O nome "' + new_user.title() + '" está disponível.')
    else:
       print('Forneça outro nome.')
```